# Jquery How to position:fixed an element until the end of a certain div of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element which I only want to be `position: fixed` until the end of a certain div. I was able make work somehow but still I can't the positioning work 100% smooth, so maybe you can help me out?

```js
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
      var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

      var containerOffset = $(".content").offset().top;
      var containerHeight = $(".content").height();
      var f1 = parseInt(containerHeight);
      var f2 = parseInt(containerOffset);
      var sum = f1 + f2;

        if (scrollTop > sum - 240) {
          $(".item")
            .css("position", "relative")
            .css("top", f1 + "px")
        }  else {
          $(".item")
            .css("position", "fixed")
            .css("top", "20px");
        }

    });
```

```css
.content {
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: grey;
}

.item {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.another {
  background: orange; 
  height: 400px;
}

.more {
  background: darkblue;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item">
      scroll only until end of grey CONTENT DIV
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="another">
    <h1>Another div</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="more">
    <h1>More content</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: Why are you subtracting 240 from the sum in the if check?

Answer (score 1):

Add this css to your html

```
div.sticky_top {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 20px;
}
```

and add `sticky_top` class to your item div - no need for javascript or jquery

```
<div class="item sticky_top">
    scroll only until end of grey CONTENT DIV
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxZaPd

Comment: It's always cleanest to use built-in functionality.  Assuming that built-in functionality exists (tip: it doesn't if you still need to support IE11, which many people do):  https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak when it starts to scroll by adjusting

```
if (scrollTop > sum - 240) {
```

it's not clear where 240 came from, but match this with your `.item` `top` attribute to give

```
if (scrollTop > sum - 20) {
```

and it gives what (it looks like) you're after

```js
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
      var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

      var containerOffset = $(".content").offset().top;
      var containerHeight = $(".content").height();
      var f1 = parseInt(containerHeight);
      var f2 = parseInt(containerOffset);
      var sum = f1 + f2;

        if (scrollTop > sum - 20) {
          $(".item")
            .css("position", "relative")
            .css("top", f1 + "px")
        }  else {
          $(".item")
            .css("position", "fixed")
            .css("top", "20px");
        }

    });
```

```css
.content {
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: grey;
}

.item {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.another {
  background: orange; 
  height: 400px;
}

.more {
  background: darkblue;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item">
      scroll only until end of grey CONTENT DIV
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="another">
    <h1>Another div</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="more">
    <h1>More content</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pb0Ljtn4/20/